# hash using sha1sum using awk

Tags: hash, awk, sed, sha1

I have a "pipe-separated" file that has about 20 columns.  I want to just hash the first column which is a number like account number using sha1sum and return the rest of the columns as is.

Whats the best way I can do this using awk or sed?

```
Accountid|Time|Category|.....
8238438|20140101021301|sub1|...
3432323|20140101041903|sub2|...
9342342|20140101050303|sub1|...
```

Above is an example of the text file showing just 3 columns.  Only the first column has the hashfunction implemented on it.  Result should like:

```
Accountid|Time|Category|.....
104a1f34b26ae47a67273fe06456be1fe97f75ba|20140101021301|sub1|...
c84270c403adcd8aba9484807a9f1c2164d7f57b|20140101041903|sub2|...
4fa518d8b005e4f9a085d48a4b5f2c558c8402eb|20140101050303|sub1|...
```

Comment: Start by editing your question to include some sample input and expected output and some details on the mapping between them. And we do NOT need to see 20 columns of input. Just 4 or 5 lines each with 4 or 5 columns should be enough to represent your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an awk executable script that does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }

FNR != 1 { $1 = encodeData( $1 ) }

47

function encodeData( fld ) {
    cmd = sprintf( "echo %s | sha1sum", fld )
    cmd | getline output
    close( cmd )
    split( output, arr, " " )
    return arr[1]
    }
```

Here's the flow break down:

- Set the input and output field separators to `|`
- When the row isn't the first (header) row, re-assign `$1` to an encoded value
- Print the entire row when `47` is true (always)

Here's the `encodeData` function break down:

- Create a `cmd` to feed data to `sha1sum`
- Feed it to `getline`
- Close the `cmd`
- On my system, there's extra info after `sha1sum`, so I discard it by `split`ing the output
- Return the first field of the `sha1sum` output.

With your data, I get the following:

```
Accountid|Time|Category|.....
104a1f34b26ae47a67273fe06456be1fe97f75ba|20140101021301|sub1|...
c84270c403adcd8aba9484807a9f1c2164d7f57b|20140101041903|sub2|...
4fa518d8b005e4f9a085d48a4b5f2c558c8402eb|20140101050303|sub1|...
```

running by calling `awk.script data` (or `./awk.script data` if you bash)

**EDIT by EdMorton**:
sorry for the edit, but your script above is the right approach but needs some tweaks to make it more robust and this is much easier than trying to describe them in a comment:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }

NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) f[$i] = i; next }
{ $(f["Accountid"]) = encodeData($(f["Accountid"])); print }

function encodeData( fld,       cmd, output ) {
    cmd = "echo \047" fld "\047 | sha1sum"
    if ( (cmd | getline output) > 0 ) {
        sub(/ .*/,"",output)
    }
    else {
        print "failed to hash " fld | "cat>&2"
        output = fld
    }
    close( cmd )
    return output
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
104a1f34b26ae47a67273fe06456be1fe97f75ba|20140101021301|sub1|...
c84270c403adcd8aba9484807a9f1c2164d7f57b|20140101041903|sub2|...
4fa518d8b005e4f9a085d48a4b5f2c558c8402eb|20140101050303|sub1|...
```

The `f[]` array decouples your script from hard-coding the number of the field that needs to be hashed, the additional args for your function make them local and so always null/zero on each invocation, the `if` on getline means you won't return the previous success value if it fails (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline) and the rest is maybe more style/preference with a bit of a performance improvement.

Comment: Your script is the right approach and is very close but needs a couple of changes to make it more robust so I edited your answer to show those changes rather than posting my own answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @EdMorton That breaks if the field contains anything the shell considers a special character.

Comment: @EdMorton Try it with `foo"bar`. And remember `foo'bar`, so single quotes alone don't save you. Also dollar signs and whatnot.

Comment: @EdMorton The shell would see `echo "foo${PATH}bar"`, which would silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: @EdMorton Works in mine. Why do you think I did all that? :P Anyway, all there's left to do is `gsub(/'/, "'\\''", fld)`.

Comment: @EdMorton - I don't mind at all - SO is built that way.  I agree with most of the changes in `encodeData` and admit to short-cutting in the interest of getting out an answer before lunch.  However, I feel the `f` array is a bit heavyweight for clarity when it is possible the header for a column could change as well as its position (as a supportability issue down the line).  In either case, the field resassignment could take place in the function to cut down on duplication when calling `encodeData`.

Comment: When it's only the 1st field you're operating on, yeah, the f[] array is probably overkill as it's unlikely that the key field will change to some other position. When you have to operate on more than one field, though, doing this has saved me countless hours of re-work as I'll find columns added mid-CSV that push out field numbers but the title line remains unchanged so I try to always do it just in case. Yes, doing the reassignment inside the function would make sense.

Comment: @EdMorton - We've had different experiences.  In cases where the header fields are internationalizable the text is not as "easy" to maintain as column numbers so I'm less inclined to trust header text.  To check if field or sub field numbers have changed, I would throw in a  test like `NF != known_fld_cnt` and write any invalid lines to an error file.  If a column has changed semantically, then I generally pray there's some versioning/differentiation info available to handle two or more kinds of data in the same column.

Answer (score 5):

What the Best Way™ is is up for debate. One way to do it with awk is

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NR == 1 { print } NR != 1 { gsub(/'\''/, "'\'\\\\\'\''", $1); command = ("echo '\''" $1 "'\'' | sha1sum -b | cut -d\\  -f 1"); command | getline hash; close(command); $1 = hash; print }' filename
```

That is

```
BEGIN {
  OFS = FS          # set output field separator to field separator; we will use
                    # it because we meddle with the fields.
}
NR == 1 {           # first line: just print headers.
  print
}
NR != 1 {           # from there on do the hash/replace
  # this constructs a shell command (and runs it) that echoes the field
  # (singly-quoted to prevent surprises) through sha1sum -b, cuts out the hash
  # and gets it back into awk with getline (into the variable hash)
  # the gsub bit is to prevent the shell from barfing if there's an apostrophe
  # in one of the fields.
  gsub(/'/, "'\\''", $1);
  command = ("echo '" $1 "' | sha1sum -b | cut -d\\  -f 1")
  command | getline hash
  close(command)

  # then replace the field and print the result.
  $1 = hash
  print
}
```

You will notice the differences between the shell command at the top and the awk code at the bottom; that is all due to shell expansion. Because I put the awk code in single quotes in the shell commands (double quotes are not up for debate in that context, what with `$1` and all), and because the code contains single quotes, making it work inline leads to a nightmare of backslashes. Because of this, my advice is to put the awk code into a file, say `foo.awk`, and run

```
awk -F'|' -f foo.awk filename
```

instead.

Comment: you can avoid most of the backslash nightmare with octals :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `echo "'s morgens - O'Neill - d'Or - maître d'" | mawk '1; 
gsub(_ = "\47", "&\\\\&&") + sub(/.*/, "printf "_"%s"_" $"_"&"_)_'` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: `'s morgens - O'Neill - d'Or - maître d'` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::: `printf '%s' $''\''s morgens - O'\''Neill - d'\''Or - maître d'\'''` :::::: despite `mawk` not being `UTF8` aware, nonetheless the accented `î` was properly retained

Comment: That string wasn't redundantly quoted in both single *AND* double quotes - I intentionally chose test cases of French and Dutch words that led-with or trailed-with the apostrophe/single-quote. (the `printf` bit was just me being self-pedantic for no reason). [ "In the morning", a common Irish family name, "gold/golden", and "head waiter/guest-host" ]